# Phonegap Multiple Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I'm currently working on an application in cordova. Since I have more pages I tried to add a menu. On the first page (index.html) there is some output, on the second file (settings.html) I want to make a Ajax-Request to a external server.

In the `<head>`-Tag all stylesheets and jQuery and Cordova is included. In the `<body>`-Tag some Ajax-calls are made.

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="onLoad();">    
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-corners="false">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="settings.html">Settings</a>
</div>
<!-- Ajax Requests -->
</body>
```

If I hit Settings I get to the html-page and the code will be displayed, but the code jQuery/js-code will not be executed. (I tried an alert, but it's not working)

Can you tell me what possibilities I have to include another page with working js-code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [***jQuery Mobile***](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/) , you can use **Single Page Application**([***SPA***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)) for multiple pages in [***Cordova***](http://cordova.apache.org/) like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>   
 </head>
<body> 
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Home</h1>            
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" >
            <p>Home Page</p>
            <a data-role="none" href="#setting">Setting</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="setting">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Setting</h1>
            <a href=""  data-rel="back" >Back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" >
            <p>Setting Page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
 $(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#index",function(){
   // You ajax call for index page
 });

 $(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#setting",function(){
   // You ajax call for setting page
 });
</script>
<html>
```

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/ujoo39vp/)

Comment: Thanks!
Is there a possiblity to fire the event from "#index" if the event is called and at starting the page? I need both events, because when the page is called the event should fire as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a script that will fire when the page is fully loaded into the DOM.

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          -- call your$.ajax({}) here --
      });
 </script>
```

OR

```
 <script>
  (function(){
     call your $.ajax({}) here --
   }();
 </script>
```

Comment: So I include the script by `<a href="settings.html">Settings</a>` and in the settings.html I put your function?

Comment: You need to include the <script></script> in the head of your settngs.html page.  It will execute the function once the page is fully loaded.